# Litecoin tagged addresses

Tags: litecoin

I know that on blockchain info there is a list of bitcoin tagged addresses https://blockchain.info/tags. I'm wondering if there exists something similar for Litecoin, since I did not find any information about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those tagged addresses are only for blockchain.info. They are not part of the Bitcoin blockchain, they are local only to blockchain.info. So you would need a service like blockchain.info that maintains a database of addresses that are tagged, but those tags would only apply to that service only. AFAIK, there is no such service.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if existed such a service, but apparently it does not exist, currently. Thanks!